# How to determine records to be deleted in related/other tables before running DELETE statement in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I'm relatively new to SQL Server. I wanted to delete some records from a table. I wanted to run the statement:

```
DELETE Table1 
WHERE COLUMN1 = 7
```

So, before running my query, I ran the following Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE COLUMN1 = 7
```

The results of the query were 3 rows.

I ran the original `DELETE` query in SSMS and it showed:

```
324 ROWS affected
0 ROWS affected
3 ROWS affected
```

I'm guessing there are some sort of either triggers or foreign keys somewhere that caused this statement to delete additional 324 rows in other table. I restored the database to resolve the issue.

The question is: is there a way to show/list any/all records to be deleted based on my `DELETE` statement before I execute it in SSMS?

Comment: Use `begin tran`, run your query, then either `commit` or `rollback`. If you had a trigger (we don't know if you don't know) you probably *want* the rows deleted since it's most likely maintaining referential integrity.

Comment: `begin tran/rollback` combined with getting the *actual* (not estimated) query plan, should tell you everything

Comment: hi @Stu how to get the rows deleted in the middle of the statement?

Comment: @Charlieface how do I get the actual query plan?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

To run a data-modification query and be confident it has the desired and expected outcome, proceed as follows.

*Always* preceed your statement(s) with `begin tran`.

Make sure you retrieve the actual *execution plan* - (CTRL + M) or Query menu > Include Actual Execution Plan.

Before running your query, run `set statistics io on`

Run your query, making sure you have included `begin tran`

Examine the *execution plan* tab which will show you every table involved in the query.

Look at the *messages* tab for the IO statistics, it will list you every table and the amount of IO performed against each.

If everything looks correct, run `commit tran`, or if you want to cancel the query run `rollback`

*Be aware that if you are working on a production system your transaction could block other queries until you either `commit` or `rollback`.*

Answer (score 0):

Utilized ON DELETE CASCADE this will specifies that the child data is deleted when the parent data is deleted.

Below is an example when we create the second foreign key with cascade as delete rule then the above delete command runs successfully by deleting records in the child table “States” which in turn deletes records in the second child table “Cities.

```
CREATE TABLE Countries

(CountryID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CountryName VARCHAR(50),
CountryCode VARCHAR(3))


CREATE TABLE States

(StateID INT PRIMARY KEY,
StateName VARCHAR(50),
StateCode VARCHAR(3),
CountryID INT)

GO


CREATE TABLE Cities
(CityID INT,
CityName varchar(50),
StateID INT)
GO

INSERT INTO Countries VALUES (1,'United States','USA')

INSERT INTO Countries VALUES (2,'United Kingdom','UK')

INSERT INTO States VALUES (1,'Texas','TX',1)
INSERT INTO States VALUES (2,'Arizona','AZ',1)

INSERT INTO Cities VALUES(1,'Texas City',1)
INSERT INTO Cities values (1,'Phoenix',2)

GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[States]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_States_Countries] FOREIGN KEY([CountryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Countries] ([CountryID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cities]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Cities_States] FOREIGN KEY([StateID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[States] ([StateID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

DELETE FROM Countries where CountryID =1
```